# Get maven-jetty-plugin to deploy-war and serve external static content at the same time

Tags: web-applications, maven, jetty

I'm writing integration tests for a web app using the maven-jetty-plugin. I'm using the deploy-war goal inside the pre-integration-test phase. The web app depends on another web application I would like to mock by serving static content from the same jetty instance.

here's the relevant part of my jetty config:

```
<execution>
    <id>start-jetty</id>
    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>deploy-war</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <connectors>
            <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <port>${jetty.port}</port>
            </connector>
        </connectors>
        <daemon>true</daemon>
        <webApp>${build.directory}/motown2-war.war</webApp>
        <webAppConfig>
            <extraClasspath>${basedir}/target/classes/;${basedir}/target/test-classes</extraClasspath>
            <contextPath>/${context.path}</contextPath>
        </webAppConfig>
        <contextHandlers>           
            <contextHandler implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                <contextPath>/other</contextPath>
                <resourceBase>/opt/data</resourceBase>
            </contextHandler>
        </contextHandlers>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

I've based this config on
http://blog.markfeeney.com/2009/12/scala-lift-jetty-6-static-content-and.html,
but the configurations for the context handler seems to be ignored. I can't
find a trace of this in the log files, jetty returns 404 instead of static
content, the web app itself is running.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

the resourceHandlers configuration only works for the jetty:run goal, so I'm now
working with an empty webapp in my test project, which overlays the webapp to
be tested:

```
<execution>
    <id>start-jetty</id>
    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <connectors>
            <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <port>${jetty.port}</port>
            </connector>
        </connectors>
        <daemon>true</daemon>
        <webApp>${build.directory}/motown2-war.war</webApp>
        <webAppConfig>
            <extraClasspath>${basedir}/target/classes/;${basedir}/target/test-classes</extraClasspath>
            <contextPath>/${context.path}</contextPath>
            <baseResource implementation="org.mortbay.resource.ResourceCollection">
                <resourcesAsCSV>../motown2-war/src/main/webapp,src/main/webapp</resourcesAsCSV>
            </baseResource>
        </webAppConfig>
        <contextHandlers>           
            <contextHandler implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                <contextPath>/other</contextPath>
                <resourceBase>/opt/data</resourceBase>
            </contextHandler>
        </contextHandlers>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Comment: i would update to the org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin for jetty 7 or jetty 8 depending on the servlet api version you need.  there has been a fair amount of development on the plugin since jetty 6 days.